# Insert liveCuePoints in live broadcast - getting error 403 Forbidden

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

We have a verified app with the following scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube

This means we can use the YouTube Data API and YouTube Content ID API (for YouTube Partners).

We are trying to do ad inserts ([insert LiveCuepoints](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveCuepoints/insert)) for a live broadcast on a YouTube partner channel, which is connected via our verified app. We are getting the following error when we use the LiveCuepoint insert API endpoint:

Request

```
POST /youtube/partner/v1/liveCuepoints?channelId={channelId}&onBehalfOfContentOwner={contentOwnerId} HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 57

{"broadcastId":"{broadcastId}","settings":{"cueType":"ad"}}
```

Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Other requests (with the same credentials) to the YouTube Content ID API (such as [listing contentOwners](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/contentOwners) or [listing liveBroadcasts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list)) are working fine and without errors.

We’ve tried debugging this issue for many hours, researched online and tried different solutions but couldn’t get this to work. Is there a special scope, setting or access needed to do ad inserts in a live broadcast? Is anyone having working example code to do liveCuepoint inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested: I found the solution.

We connected (via our verified app) as a **channel**. This was a mistake, you have to authenticate with an **account**, and this account must have administrator rights.

Now you receive an access token which can access all content owners and channels connected to that account. Inserting liveCuePoints now works fine!